# R squared generated from regression with randomly generated variables

Tags: r-squared

If you regress randomly generated independent variables on a randomly generated dependent variable, is the expected R squared value simply a function of n (the # observations) and k (the # of independent variables)?   If so, why is this?

In some old regression course notes I was re-reading, I see that the expected R-squared in this case is k / (n-k-1).  I tried this with some randomly generated data (e.g. n=100 and k=20) and indeed got a value very close to 0.2532, but I don't understand how it can be this simple.  Thanks for any color anyone might have.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your formula or your simulation.  For the formula I obtain $k/(n-1)$ and my simulations in `R` agree with this.  Note that your formula yields nonsense whenever $k$ exceeds $n-k-1$: it gives an expected $R^2$ greater than $1$!

Comment: The math seems to be correct according to... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181652/expected-value-of-r2-the-coefficient-of-determination-under-the-null-hypoth by https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/28746/alecos-papadopoulos

Comment: @jeffalltogether whuber's math is correct, indeed. And this question can be considered a duplicate.