# What's the distribution of $|y-z|^2/|y-\bar{y}|^2$ for vectors with i.i.d. standard normal coordinates?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, density-function, gamma-distribution

Let $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$ and $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n$ be samples of size $n$ of a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. My goal is to find the distribution of
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - z_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \bar{y})^2},$$
where $\bar{y} = (y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_n) / n$.

My first idea was to approximate the denominator of the expression by $n$, since
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \bar{y})^2\approx 1.$$
In other words, we approximate the expression by the Mean Squared Error between the samples.

$(y_i - z_i)^2$ follows a $\Gamma(1/2, 4)$ distribution, since it is the square of a $\mathcal{N}(0, 2)$. Then, the distribution of the whole thing is a $\Gamma(n/2, 4/n)$. This seems to be working well enough as an approximation, but the first assumption is not correct, I believe. Using Python, I have produced some simulations which seem to confirm my suspicion:

[image: Plot of the simulation]

Then, I tried expressing the whole distribution as a quotient of distributions. The numerator has distribution $\Gamma(n/2, 4)$, but I am not sure about the denominator. I know that the quotient of $\Gamma$ distributions is known so, if the denominator follows a $\Gamma$ distribution, we would be done. However, I do not know how to show this. Any hints? Thank you in advance.

Edit: by a bit of educated trial and error, and using simulation, it looks like the solution is a $\beta'(n, n-1, 1, 2)$ distribution. The way I got to this is by taking the quotient of $\Gamma(n/2,4)$ (the distribution of the numerator) and $\Gamma((n-1)/2, 2)$ (what I think is the distribution of the denominator). However, taking the quotient of these two results in a $\beta'(n/2, (n-1)/2, 1, 2)$ distribution, which is not the correct solution (again, by simulation). Here is what my simulation results look like ($n=30$, $10000$ trials):

[image: Simulation results with beta prime]

Am I computing the quotient incorrectly?

Comment: If you could explain the statistical motivation for this question it might give us some insight into solutions -- and help us verify that this really is the question you need answered.

Comment: The thing I care about is the distribution of the right side of the expression in the statement. Whether it really is $1-R^2$ or not does not really matter, to me.

Comment: Then this becomes purely a math problem: you ask about the quotient of two homogeneous quadratic forms.  The solution will be a matter of linear algebra to find a suitable decomposition of those forms.

Comment: If $R^2$ is R squared from a linear regression then some results on its distribution are available at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130069/what-is-the-distribution-of-r2-in-linear-regression-under-the-null-hypothesis, viz a beta distribution. From the properties listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution, $1-R^2$ then is also beta, but with the parameters flipped.

Comment: I have removed the $R^2$ part of the question, as it was confusing.

Comment: As to the denominator, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121662/why-is-the-sampling-distribution-of-variance-a-chi-squared-distribution#:~:text=The%20sampling%20distribution%20of%20the,of%20interest%20is%20normally%20distributed).

Comment: @RayBern The $\beta'$ distribution you use is true for the ratio of *independent* gamma variables, in your case the numerator and denominator are clearly not independent. It's interesting that the actual distribution seems to have the similar form that you found

Comment: @J.Delaney absolutely right. It is interesting indeed, it seems to be working with any value of $n$ I pick

Comment: The $\beta^\prime$ distribution fails when you try this with small $n$. It is especially clear when $n = 2$.